# How do you assign an event handler to multiple elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I know how to do so with jQuery, and I know how to do so with event delegation. But how do you do so in plain JavaScript?

For example, how do you assign an event handler to a bunch of `li`s?

I see that `var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');`. Returns an array-like thing. Do you just loop through and assign handlers? I feel like there must be a better way. If not, what's the best way to loop through the array-like thing (and what is the array-like thing called?)?

Comment: Is this a serious question? Yes, when you have a collection, and you want to apply some behavior to each element in the collection, you can iterate the collection and operate on individual members. There is no better way. This is exactly what jQuery does.

Comment: @squint I figured that there would be a way to do something like `li.<add listeners to each>`. I'm still learning to program, but in hindsight what you said makes sense. Still, I think it's a completely understandable question for a student to have.

Comment: you should probably use delegation instead of adding a lot of events manually in a loop. you just buind the click (or whatever) to the UL instead of the LI, and check e.target instead of this inside the handler.

Comment: Four word answer: "One at a time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should loop through the collection and assign the handlers individually. jQuery also does this behind the scenes.

`querySelectorAll` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is an array-like object.

For looping through the list, you can either use a `for` loop:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
    l = list.length,
    li;

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
   li = list.item(i);
   // ...
}
```

Or use the `forEach` method:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'), function(li) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: How do you loop through it? `forEach` isn't working.

Comment: @AdamZerner: With a `for` loop. "array-like" means that the object has a `length` and numerical properties.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I wasn't sure what the keys were so I was afraid to do a `for` loop but the keys seem to be numerical indicies like an array.